# Difference between contraction rate and convergence rate

Tags: convergence

I am slightly confused about the concept of contraction rate. For me it sounds equivalent to a convergence rate. Could somebody clear up the difference for me?
I have those two definitions of convergence and contraction rate from the book [Numerical Optimal Control (M. Diehl)](https://www.syscop.de/files/2019ss/NOC/book-NOCSE.pdf): 
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Easiest way to understand the difference is to draw a 1D figure.